# What happens when the credit card expires on a recurring Paypal payment for a Non Member user of PayPal?

Tags: paypal, payment

The problem we have is - with the regular Paypal payment system we have now, when a new member creates an account with their credit card without being a PayPal member, in the future, there is no way they can update or change their credit card information they submitted. And it is a big problem because when their credit card expires PayPal won't be able to charge it and the members won't be able to update it.

Is there is  Proper solution for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

Notify the user that their payment declined, and add a button for them to change their payment details (by creating a new paypal prompt). Usually, you should end their service. However, you can always provide a buffer of a few days to give them time to update their information.

Comment: Hi, @Rus But how it will do? since all the card-related (including expiration date) information is saved in the Paypal Server, how we can get it? and the update facility should be provided by Paypal right?

Comment: @NamithaBalachandran Hi, that goes beyond my information about PayPal, here's a good place to ask: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-Integration-Technical/ct-p/mts